# How do you describe these head movements?

Tags: phrase-request

For example:

1. You are writing a story (or a note) and you write a line that you like and so you tilt your head this way and that while you read it over and consider it.
2. Your hear a friend say something really odd or incredible and you tilt your head to show disbelief.
3. Your pet dog moving its head this way and that on hearing you make strange noises.

How do you describe these head movements?

Answer (score 7):

That is called [cocking](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/cock?s=t) your head:

> to set or turn up or to one side, often in an assertive, jaunty, or significant manner:

[metafilter](http://ask.metafilter.com/32354/headcocking-for-understanding) has an interesting post regarding the function that head-cocking can serve.

Answer (score 1):

Just some ideas of mine.

1. [**Tilt side to side.**](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/side-to-side#English) Because I like your chosen word, tilt.
2. [**Shake.**](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/shake_one%27s_head) You can shake your head in disbelief
3. [**Jiggle.**](http://thesaurus.com/browse/jiggle?s=t)To move back and forth. More often than not used for kids when they fidget, or the movement you make with a door handle when it refuses to open. Could it also be used to describe the movements of a dog's head, I wonder?